# Get data from any Web API to console application

Tags: c#, api, console-application, openweathermap

So, for example there is [Open Wearther API](https://openweathermap.org/api). Are there ways to get data from there to use in my C# console application?

Comment: Yes, there is. Any other questions? Perhaps a coding problem that you've *attempted and failed at*?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the HttpClient.  Here is a basic example but if you google httpclient you will see many examples:

```
 HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
        http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthHeader);

        http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent","myuser@me.com");
       var response = await http.GetAsync(completeUrl);
        string jsonstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```